# No Route Matches DELETE Sessions Api

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, session, authentication

I've started to create an Api for my rails application. I am currently creating the Sessions Controller for Log in.

But for some reason I am getting this error

```
Started DELETE "/api/v1/sessions/?auth_token=6157d3673725013ebddbb5e26e8cd64756949110" 
for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-29 18:54:18 -0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/api/v1/sessions"):
```

I am not understanding why this is happening. Sign Out seems to work perfectly on the actual web application.

I know it may need an ID according to the rake routes but I'm not sure how to implement this.

**API CONTROLLER**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
      skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token,
                       :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

      respond_to :json

      def destroy
        sign_out
        render :status => 200,
           :json => { :success => true,
                      :info => "Logged Out",
                      :data => {} }
      end

    end
  end
end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def destroy
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

**SESSION HELPER**

```
def sign_out 
  current_user = nil
  cookies.delete(:remember_token)
end
```

**ROUTES**

```
### API Routes
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
    resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

**RAKE ROUTES**

```
api_v1_sessions POST   /api/v1/sessions(.:format)                        
api/v1/sessions#create {:format=>"json"}

api_v1_session DELETE /api/v1/sessions/:id(.:format)                    
api/v1/sessions#destroy {:format=>"json"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resource)

You can use `resource` instead of the `resources` routes helper. It's used to create routes for a singular resource that you don't access using IDs.

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  namespace :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
    resource :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  end
end
```

which will give you

```
GET       /session/new
POST      /session
DELETE    /session
```

Comment: This is the command I am using now: curl -v -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -X DELETE http://localhost:3000/api/v1/session/\?auth_token\=3b774e0d8f7abdf7dabfcbb45a6ff11be2288d2d

Comment: but i still get this error message: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/api/v1/session"):

Comment: And `rake routes` shows the `DELETE "/api/v1/session"` route?

Comment: delete now has this:                                                      DELETE /api/session(.:format)                                                                                                   api/v1/sessions#destroy {:format=>"json"}

Comment: Ok I edited my answer to reflect this. The problem is that `scope module: :v1` omits the `v1` in the url while just using `namespace` will include the `v1`.

Comment: going of that logic, i also made it work by taking off the "v1" from my actual curl DELETE command above. Thanks for your help :)